# Getting text in python scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I get this code from a website:

```
import scrapy

class BrickSetSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "brickset_spider"
    start_urls = ['http://brickset.com/sets/year-2016']

    def parse(self, response):
        SET_SELECTOR = '.set'
        for brickset in response.css(SET_SELECTOR):

            NAME_SELECTOR = 'h1 a ::text'
            yield {
                'name': brickset.css(NAME_SELECTOR).extract(),
            }
```

I use the code for crawling data. This is a sample result when I run the code:
[image: ![enter image description here]

The name is the result of extract() method. This is the inspect element (in chrome):

[image]

I want to ask about the way to get the result for name is 10805: Around the World or only Around the World. How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get "10805: Around the World" change your yield to:

```
 yield {
            'name': " ".join(brickset.css(NAME_SELECTOR).extract()),
        }
```

To get "Around the World" change your yield to:

```
yield {
            'name': brickset.css(NAME_SELECTOR).extract()[-1],
        }
```